# Spring boot app Can't load library after deploying into tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, centos, tomcat9

In my spring boot app, i load a **.so** library using

```
System.load("/path/library.so");
```

This is working fine running from tool. But after deploying this app into tomcat server in CentOS 7, it's giving following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /path/library.so
```

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't there a stack trace? Is it possibly 32 vs 64 bit?

Comment: I have checked the catalina.out log only "Can't load library" found. It should not 32 vs 64 bit problem as i can run from Tool without any problem.

Comment: Is the user running tomcat permitted to access this file?